# Reference vectors within function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with various variables.

```
'data.frame':   324 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ caldt     : Date, format: "1990-01-31" "1990-02-28" "1990-03-30" 
 $ X30bd     : num  -0.0429 -0.00595 -0.00265 -0.03033 0.04894 ...
 $ X20bd     : num  -0.0396 -0.00269 -0.00227 -0.02729 0.04885 ...
 $ X10bd     : num  -0.02441 -0.00207 -0.0017 -0.0174 0.03283 ...
```

...

I create a vector containing the variables of interest on which I want to perform analysis.

```
endowmentAssetClasses <- c("X30bd", "X20bd")
```

I want to create a different R object for each variable on which I will perform analysis.

```
for (i in endowmentAssetClasses) {
     paste0(i,".gpd.fit") <- gpd.tail(paste0("endowMVEVdata$",i),upper=quantile(paste0("endowMVEVdata$",i),0.9), 
                     lower=quantile(paste0("endowMVEVdata$",i),0.1))
}
```

I get an error though,

```
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

meaning that I am referencing the vector "endowMVEVdata$X30bd" and so forth as characters, but I am at a loss to create the gpd object

```
x30bd.gpd.fit
```

and

```
x20gd.gpd.fit
```

to contain the output from the function "gpd.tail" in a "loop."  Everything works fine if I type the names directly, with a line entry for each variable I want the analysis, but how can I reference the vectors in a look so that the function recognizes numeric data instead of a character?

Comment: You may need `assign` and `get`

Comment: `paste0()` gives a character as result. Please read the fine manual of the function, section **Value**.

Answer (score 1):

Like @akrun said, you could indeed make it work with `assign` and `get`.

It would look like:

```
for (i in endowmentAssetClasses) {
  assign(
    paste0(i, ".gpd.fit"),
    gpd.tail(
      endowMVEVdata[[i]], 
      upper = quantile(endowMVEVdata[[i]], 0.9), 
      lower = quantile(endowMVEVdata[[i]], 0.1)
    )
  )
}
```

Actually, `get` is not needed here. `get(paste0("endowMVEVdata$", i))` wouldn't work. `eval(parse(text = paste0("endowMVEVdata$", i)))` would, but really, don't.

But:

```
fortunes::fortune(236)
# The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully
# understand why you should never use the assign function.
# -- Greg Snow
# R-help (July 2009)
```

The R way is not to work with multiple variables in your workspace and loops, but rather to store similar things in lists and pass them to functions. A direct translation would be:

```
gpd.fit.list <- lapply(
  setNames(nm = endowmentAssetClasses),
  function(x) gpd.tail(
    endowMVEVdata[[x]], 
    upper = quantile(endowMVEVdata[[x]], 0.9), 
    lower = quantile(endowMVEVdata[[x]], 0.1)
  ) 
)
```

Or more simply:

```
gpd.fit.list <- lapply(
  endowMVEVdata[, endowmentAssetClasses, drop = FALSE],
  function(y) gpd.tail(y, upper = quantile(y, 0.9), lower = quantile(y, 0.1))
)
```

Note that this code is not tested, so it may not work without some adaptation. You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for both replies.  The simple approach from Aurele worked wonderfully, on a test set of variables, then the function crashed on a couple of others.  So, I'm not going to be able to automate this like I thought.  Thanks again for both replies.